# Let $\{a_n\}$ be bounded sequence, satisfied $a_{n+1} \geq a_n - \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Problem:** Let $\{a_n\}$ be bounded sequence, satisfied $a_{n+1} \geq a_n - \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n}, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

**My attempt:** consider sequence $\{x_n\} = \left\{ a_n - \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \right\}$. Obviously $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. Then we have $x_{n+1} - x_n = a_{n+1} - \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n} - a_n + \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} = a_{n+1} - a_n + \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n} \geq a_n - \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n} - a_n + \displaystyle\frac{1}{2^n} = 0$. Hence, $\{x_n\}$ is a non-decreasing sequence, apply $\{x_n\}$ is a convergent sequence. Here, can we conclude that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent? If we can, please explain how can we do that. Sorry for my poor English. Thank all!

Comment: Your $\{x_n\}$ is non-decreasing.

Comment: I see, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $a_n = x_n + 1/ 2^{n-1}$, which is a sum of convergent sequences and hence convergent.